# Can you stretch the CSS grid to fill the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm wanting to stretch out the grid to look like the second image attached in the imgur below (sorry I can't post directly on I don't have enough points to post the image directly)

My code:

```css
.container {  
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 2.4fr 1.3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr [F] 1fr;
    /* gap: 1px 0px; */
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
      "One oneTitle oneDescrip Picture"
      "Two twoTitle twoDescrip Picture"
      "Three threeTitle threeDescrip Picture"
      "Four fourTitle fourDescrip Picture";
  }
  
  .One { grid-area: One; }
  
  .Two { grid-area: Two;  }
  
  .Three { grid-area: Three; }
  
  .Four { grid-area: Four; }
  
  .oneTitle { grid-area: oneTitle;  }
  
  .twoTitle { grid-area: twoTitle; }
  
  .threeTitle { grid-area: threeTitle; }
  
  .fourTitle { grid-area: fourTitle; }
  
  .oneDescrip { grid-area: oneDescrip; }
  
  .twoDescrip { grid-area: twoDescrip; }
  
  .threeDescrip { grid-area: threeDescrip; }
  
  .fourDescrip { grid-area: fourDescrip; }
  
  .Picture { grid-area: Picture; }
  
  .One,.Two,.Three,.Four {
      font-size: 60px;
      color: lightgray;

  }

  .oneTitle, .twoTitle, .threeTitle, .fourTitle, .oneDescrip, .twoDescrip, .threeDescrip, .fourDescrip {
    /* padding-top: 35px; */
    color: black;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }

  
  .oneTitle, .twoTitle, .threeTitle, .fourTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="One">1</div>
      <hr>
      <div class="Two">2</div>
      <div class="Three">3</div>
      <div class="Four">4</div>
      <div class="oneTitle">Connect your Crowds</div>
      <div class="twoTitle">Gamify the Experience</div>
      <div class="threeTitle">Engage with Business Growth</div>
      <div class="fourTitle">Continuous Interaction</div>
      <div class="oneDescrip">Descript</div>
      <div class="twoDescrip">Descript</div>
      <div class="threeDescrip">whehwehahha</div>
      <div class="fourDescrip">Descriptjwsenwejwje</div>
      <div class="Picture"><img id="block3img" src="https://i.imgur.com/PEbCBjt.png")></div>
      </div>
```

What it looks like: [image]

What I want it to look like: [image]

Comment: "*Can you stretch the...grid to fill the width of the screen?*" - obviously, yes; where did you get stuck when you tried? What did you try yourself, what went wrong? The fact that *something* went wrong suggests either a misunderstanding of the layout you're using, or of some aspect of CSS that we're quite probably very happy to help with.

Answer (score 1):

In the `.container` rule set make this declaration. `width: 100%;`

Comment: @WillCrawford try this instead `width: fit-content`. It might not work because it will just fit everything..

Comment: Thanks for the response! ```width: 100%``` didn't work on it's own, but ```min-width: 100%``` worked perfectly.

Comment: Solution doesn't work

Comment: @OscarZhang can you explain how since I relooked at this and it seems like it should still work.